# Open twitter/instagram page on app

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone-8.1, instagram

I am looking for a method to open a twitter/instagram link on the native app.

For example : 
This link 
https://mobile.twitter.com/become90

Should be opened in Twitter app.

And this link: 
http://instagram.com/become90#

Should be opened in available instagram app

Answer (score 2):

INSTAGRAM
Instagram://user?username=*insertyourusername*

TWITTER
Twitter://user?screen_name=*insertyourusername*